# PopToViewController not updating UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

I am trying to pop the view controller stack twice, right now I have got this

```
UIViewController* controller = nil;

for (UIViewController* c in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if (c.class == [ControllerIWantToPopTo class]) {
        controller = c;
        break;
    }
}

if (controller) {
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
    return;
}
```

This works as intended, but the the UINavigationBar becomes corrupted.

My stack looks like this `anotherController -> ControllerIWanToPopTo -> MiddleController -> ControllerOnTop`

The controller stacks pops to ControllerIWantToPopTo like I want, but the buttons in the navigation bar are the buttons from MiddleController and the title is the titel from ControllerOnTop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I wanted to just test out this behavior I was running the code in `-viewDidLoad` and apparently this was causing the strange problems. My guess is that in viewDidLoad the UINavigationBar might not be completely setup and this then causes the problem.

In short: **Don't try to pop to a view controller in -viewDidLoad**.